# Defining String() class from scratch

Tags: javascript

I got this exercise from a book (without solution):

> Imagine the String() constructor didn't exist. Create a constructor function
>   MyString() that acts like String() as closely as possible. You're not
>   allowed to use any built-in string methods or properties, and remember that
>   String() doesn't exist. You can use this code to test your constructor:
>
> ```
> >>> var s = new MyString('hello');
> >>> s.length;
> ```

Yet, I have a solution but not sure I followed the requirement (that is: "I am not allowed to use any built-in string methods or properties");
And here's my solution:

```
function MyString(string) {
    this.length = 0;
    for(var i in string) { 
        this.length++;      
    }
}
var x = new MyString("Hello");
x.length;
```

The one that I am not sure about is the for-in loop. could you tell me what is the data type of **string** variable in that loop? Is that kind of array or Am I using it as String (that is I did break the requirement)?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well you can't get a string ___into___ the class without using ___any___ strings to begin with, so I think the question is pointless (you could technically pass it in as dec numbers, but that's just stupid).  Basically, I think the point is to initialize the class however, then never use `String.prototype` functions again (e.g. initialize it like `this.letters = string.split( '' )`.  You'd then need to `indexOf`, `toLowerCase`, `toUpperCase`, etc

Comment: The data type would be string for that code. i.e.: `typeof string == 'string'` (primitive string) and `string instanceof String` (inherits `String` object).

Comment: Yes, that's it. But you won't be able to pass other string format which won't be a string primitive or a string object (e.g.: `new String("hello")`).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the data type of `string` in your `for` loop is indeed String. However, you are not using any native String methods to compute the length, so I'm fairly sure you've met the requirement (for the length property anyway).

That said, I agreed with @cwolves in that it is going to be extremely difficult to pass in a different data type to your constructor (given that JavaScript has so few of them) without violating the requirement that "you're not allowed to use any built-in string methods or properties".

As far as your initialization loop, kudos for not violating the requirement but it won't work. What you'll get is an array like this:

```
[
    "0",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
]
```

To avoid a super long post, here's a fiddle with a quick and dirty version of a partial implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/CtF2Q/

Caveats to the fiddle:

The following methods are not implemented:

- charCodeAt
- fromCharCode
- replace
- search
- split

The following methods are only partially implemented:

- indexOf
- lastIndexOf
- match
- toLowerCase
- toUpperCase